# What is the new Constable badge exactly?

Tags: discussion, badges

Today, I noticed there are two new badges in the community (especially for moderators): [Constable badge](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/badges/113/constable) and [Sheriff badge](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/badges/114/sheriff).

Whereas I understand what Sheriff badge is, I didn't understand how to get the Constable badge.

Can anyone can explain me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pro tempore moderators are "for the time being" or "temporary" moderators that are appointed by StackExchange staff when a new stack site is in beta before it has enough users to be able to elect moderators.  See: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/

Now that this site is large enough to hold elections, moderators will no longer be appointed and there will be no new opportunities to earn the Constable badge.